# PHP and MySql sessions across pages

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to keep some variables across many pages in php until I log out. For example, if I enter the company name in a form, I should be able to retrieve it via session across other pages. How can this be done? Also, how can I destroy those session? I am using MySql database to store data.

Comment: You've kinda' answered this yourself....sessions. All you need to do it read the very fine manual on sessions.

Comment: There are many tutorials based on *session management*. First have a look. Then, if problem comes. Feel free to ask. But, as for now, we can't help much as you have *not provided* your tried code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its quite simple. You will use following code inside the form success page.

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();

// I am assuming in submission from you have used POST method and field name as 'company'
$_SESSION["company"] = $_POST["company"]
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Company is <?php echo $_SESSION["company"]?></p>

<?php
// removes all session variables and destroy the session
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

store variable in session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["company_name"] = "some company";
```

retrieve in any pages using

```
session_start();
$company_name = $_SESSION["company_name"];
```

Destroy the session

```
session_unset();
```